# What does the "greater than" operator ">" mean for PyTorch tensors?

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor `it` defined as:

```
import torch
it = torch.tensor([0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], device='cuda:0')
```

Given this definition, what does `it > 0` then mean?

Comment: it creates a tensor of boolean values, set to True for each i where it[i] > 0 and False otherwise

Answer (score 8):

Using the `>` operator is the same as using the [`torch.gt()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gt) function.

In other words,

```
it > 0
```

is the same as

```
torch.gt(it, 0)
```

and it returns a `ByteTensor` (a Boolean tensor) of the same `shape` as `it` where `out[i]` is True if `it[i] > 0` and False otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

As seen from the question `it` is a 1-d tensor consisting of 10 elements.
When we write `it > 0` each element of the tensor `it` is compared with 0 and the output is set as `True` or `False` depending upon whether the number is greater than 0 or not. The result is also a 1-d boolean tensor consisting of `True` and `False` values.
In your case, you will get a 1-d tensor like this: `[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,]` as none of the elements in `it` is equal to 0.

In more simpler terms,

If `result` is a variable (actually a 1-d tenosr) to store the output having the same shape as `it` then the equation `result= it > 0` can be written as:

```
if it[i]>0:
    result[i]= True
else:
    result[i]= False
```

But when it's performed as `result= it > 0`, the execution is much faster than writing our own `for/while` loop.

Hope this helps you.